# Will an incomplete mongoose document validate if it has missing, non-required keys?

Tags: validation, schema, mongoose, document

If I have a schema like

```
var kitty = Schema(
    {
        "name": {type: String, required: true},
        "age" : Number
    }
```

And on a mobile app, I build a JSON document with the contents of a form, but only include required and non-null fields, like:

```
//pseudo android app code
var kitty = {};
kitty.name = field1.value;
if (age.text !== undefined)
    kitty.age= age.text;
doHTTPSend(url, kitty);
```

Will this validate, or does a document have to match 1:1 with the schema, like:

```
var kitty = 
    {
        "name": "Sylvester",
        "age": null //or age:"", or age: 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will validate. You only *need* to pass in the fields that are required.

There's an example in the Mongoose documentation of this:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: I'm having issues re: validation and subdocuments bases on position in the subdocument array's ordinal.

Comment: I may have resolved it. I think I had a poorly designed schema where a  I had positionally dependent subdocument schemas, like: {maindoc: [{subdoc1:[]},{subdoc2:[]}}, so creating a doc with no subdoc 1 but with subdoc2 would create subdoc2 as subdoc1. It was a crap schema, I've re-designed it.